# Two ScrollPanes in Center using GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlist

Im working on this assignment and need to achieve this...

[image]

I basically need two ScrollPanes with a JList in each. I am having a hard time getting the two JScrollPane side by side so that each JList's scroll bars appear as necessary.. the second ScrollPane is covering the first...

Here is my code:

```
public Something() { 
    super("Something");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(700, 400);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());    
    center = new JPanel();
    center.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));

    String labels[] = { "A", "B", "C", "D","E", "F", "G", "H","I", "J",
    "K","L", "M", "N", "O","P", "Q", "R", "S","T", "U", "V", "W", "X", 
    "Y", "Z"};
    list1 = new JList(labels);
    list2 = new JList(labels);

    //add a JScrollPane containing JList to frame
    JScrollPane scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane1.setViewportView(list1);
    list1.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
    JScrollPane scrollPane2 = new JScrollPane();
    list2.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
    scrollPane2.setViewportView(list2);
    add(scrollPane1,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(scrollPane2,BorderLayout.CENTER);}
```

I was able to add all the other components correctly except this.

Right now I am adding a string array for demo purposes, in reality I want to add a set of files using JFileChooser and have these files listed on the left ScrollPane, and have the results of a separate process from the dispatch thread. I mention this just in case that changes anything.

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't it be `center.add(scrollPane1);` and `center.add(scrollPane2);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to add `scrollPane1` and `scrollPane2` to `center`... e.g.

```
center.add(scrollpane1) 
center.add(scrollPane2)
```

And then add `center` to the frame (`this.add(center,BorderLayout.CENTER)`).

Comment: That's not a comment, that's an answer ;)

Comment: No problem! @richportmade